# Nested Layout for Nested Resources in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, nested-resources

Is it possible to automatically assign a specified layout template to a particular controller and all of the resources nested within it, as specified in routes.rb? This layout should apply only the specified controller views and those nested within it; it does not need to be applied to every view within the application, as application.html.erb would (I'm actually using the specialized layout with the application layout for a nested layout).

So, for example, if I had

```
map.resources :news, :shallow => true do |n|
  n.resources :articles do |a|
    a.resources :comments
  end
end
```

when I visit a url like `localhost/news/1/articles/new` I should see my `news.html.erb` layout in action. As of now, I don't.

I obviously don't want to recreate the same layout file for each controller nested within the parent (even if I would pull out the meat the layout and put it in a shared partial). I'm even less thrilled about specifying the layout template in the specific controllers themselves (this specific example is kind of a temporary thing, though I will have a 'real' use-case for this a bit further down the road).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing the original question for clarity (the answers were not quite answering the central problem), I realized what I need to do is have the nested controller classes inherit from the top-level parent. Not only does this make solving the central issue easier, it fixes a few other things that have been nagging me.

(I'd say "a'doy" but there are others working on this app, which obscured what would normally be a bit more obvious.)

Answer (score 0):

For your news.html.erb problem, is that a typo? You should see your new.html.erb file that's in your views/articles folder (assuming default layout) and not a news.html.erb file. You'll have to make sure your @news instance variable is set and your form_for will be for [@news, @article] instead of just @article.

Also, you don't have to create a layout for each controller, you can create one application.html.erb in your layouts folder and all controllers that don't have a layout in the layouts folder will use application.html.erb and you don't have to specify it in your controllers, just remove the layout with the same name as the controller.

Comment: The 'news.html.erb' file to which I referred doesn't actually exist in my project; I was just continuing the from the example shown in the Rails Guides (see link in original message). The problem here is not to create a general layout for all my views; the problem is using a nested layout within the existing application.html.erb file. If you'll take a look at the references article, the idea is explained in more detail.

Again, to clarify, I have a application.html.erb nested with a second layout file. I would like the combination of the nested layouts to appear for multiple controllers.

Answer (score 0):

"*I'm even less thrilled about specifying the layout template in the controllers themselves*"

There's no reason to worry about this. This is simply what you do. It's one line of DSL code, specifically created for this purpose. Not clunky.

```
class ArticlesController < ActionController::Base
  layout :news
end
```

Comment: Again, I think the central question is being lost. I have a standard application layout that is being used on all pages, and I have a secondary layout that I'm using with it for nested layouts. What i would like is for all nested resources within one particular resource to use the nested layout template. Thanks!